# How can I overlay a colour and a pattern?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way I can add a pattern onto a colored cell through VBA such that the color of the cell remains visible?

I am trying to do a sort of Gantt chart, where the different colours represent different people, and and want the active cell to get a pattern above to get a better view of where you are with the cursor:

[image]

In below I move the cursor one cell up. The corresponding row gets a pattern, but the red colour disappears. If I move the cursor one cell up and to the left, the same happens with the yellow colour.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried VBA code below:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set PatternRng = Range("A6" & ":" & "GM" & Sheets("Source").Range("I1").Value)
PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone

If ((ActiveCell.Row >= 7) And (ActiveCell.column <= 194) And (ActiveCell.Row <= LR)) Then
    If (ActiveCell.column > 1) Then
        Set PatternRng = Range("A6:A" & LR).Offset(, ActiveCell.column - 1)
        PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternGray25
        PatternRng.Interior.PatternColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    End If
    
    Set PatternRng = Range("A6:GM6").Offset(ActiveCell.Row - 6, 0)
    PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternGray25
    PatternRng.Interior.PatternColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)
    
    Sheets("Source").Range("I2").Value = (ActiveCell.column - 1)
    Sheets("Source").Range("I3").Value = (ActiveCell.Row - 6)
End If

Sheets("Source").Range("I1").Value = LR
```

I've also tried conditional formatting through VBA but I get the same result. But as the picture below shows it is possible if you do it manuelly on a cell.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A guess, but using `.PatternColor` seems suspect. What happens if you get rid of `PatternRng.Interior.PatternColor = RGB(191, 191, 191)`?

Comment: @BigBen I've tried that, but it seems like it is just the color on the pattern. I've also tried different patterns.

Answer (score 1):

In testing, this line cleared any interior color.

```
PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternNone
```

Instead, try

```
PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid  ' Solid color
```

or maybe:

```
PatternRng.Interior.Pattern = xlPatternAutomatic ' Excel controls the pattern
```